# How can we test android native app. using jmeter

Tags: load, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I want to do load testing of android native app using Jmeter. I also want to get capacity of my app that how many users it can handle parallel , Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jmeter 2.12 with Java 7 or 8, it creates a crt file in jmeter/bin folder. It is the CA that creates the certificates.

Send this file by mail and open it in Android and install it.

In test script recorder, put in the dedicated field HTTPS domains, the domains you are trying to hit, see:

```
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder
```

Restart Android and jmeter test script recorder and try again.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am not looking to test website in android device. I want to test Android native app. So for App. also I can follow your given steps??

Comment: Yes, my answer is about native apps. If Ok you should accept answer and upvote. Thanks

Comment: Sure, will check and let you know if get any issue.

Comment: What should I put in https domain when what to test App.?